# ngForm in one component gives form values, same code in other component gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

```
    <form class="login-form" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="authenticateUser(loginForm)">
      <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" />
      <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" />
      <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
```

html code of working component is like this.

```
    <form class="register-form" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(loginForm)">
      <input name="test" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" />
      <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" />
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
      <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="voornaam" />
      <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="familienaam" />
      <button type="submit">Registreer</button>
    </form>
```

The none working code looks like this, the same but 5 fields instead of 2. I will post my component.ts code underneath to show you those files.

I hope someone can help me to solve the problem why my form values are undefined in the register component.

I worked out the login page quiet easy but something is wrong with my register.

Thanks in advance!

Working ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  endpoint: String;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.endpoint = "http://localhost:3000/";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  authenticateUser(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
    const header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let user = '{' + '\"username\":\"' + form.value.username + '\",\"password\":\"' + form.value.password + '}';
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint + 'users/login', user, { headers: header })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

None working ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  private user;  
  endpoint: String;
  constructor(private http: Http) {     
    this.endpoint = "http://localhost:3000/";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  registerUser(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    const header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let user = '{' + '\"username\":\"' + form.value.username + '\",\"password\":\"' + form.value.password + '\",\"email\":\"' + form.value.email + '\",\"lastName\":\"' + form.value.lastname + '\",\"firstName\":\"' + form.value.firstname +'}';
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint + 'users/signup', user, { headers: header })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "ngModel" to your inputs in order to access the form.value in registerUser method.

Change to:

```
<form class="login-form" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="authenticateUser(loginForm)">
      <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" ngModel />
      <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" ngModel />
      <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
```

and to:

```
<form class="register-form" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(loginForm)">
      <input name="test" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" ngModel />
      <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" ngModel />
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" ngModel />
      <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="voornaam" ngModel />
      <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="familienaam" ngModel />
      <button type="submit">Registreer</button>
    </form>
```